# How to send parameters in Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: swift, firebase, ios13, firebase-dynamic-links

I am developing an iOS app with Swift.

I want to send a parameter with Firebase Dynamic Links.

I created a Dynamic Link called https://test.page.link/test1.

I want to attach parameters as below.

> https://test.page.link/test1?id=000000

How can I get this parameter when I click on the link and launch the app?

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let rootView = ListView()

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        guard let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first(where: { $0.webpageURL != nil }) else { return }
        print("url: \(userActivity.webpageURL!)") // <- No parameters could be obtained from here.
    }

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        print("url: \(userActivity.webpageURL!)") // <- No parameters could be obtained from here.
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can not pass parameters by short-version dynamic link.
`https://PROJECTNAME.page.link/LINKNAME` is short-version dynamic link.

You can pass get-query-parameters by using long-version dynamic link.

Here is an example for passing {param1: 'one', param2: 'two'} to app.

`https://PROJECTNAME.page.link/?link=https%3A%2F%2FPROJECTNAME.page.link/LINKNAME%3Fparam1%3Done&param2%3Dtwo&apn=XXXXXX&isi=XXXXX&ibi=XXXXXX`

You can find your long-version dynamic link by clicking the ⋮ menu next to the link on the console, going in Link Details and using your 'Long Dynamic Link'. Add parameters to the inner link and they will come through in the app.